# \includegraphics: Order of operations of width and trim

Tags: graphics

Does `\includegraphics[width=X, trim= Yem 0em 0em 0em, clip]{image.pdf}`
trim then set width or the reverse?

I believe it is the former; however,
I would like to know if it is possible to choose the order.

Comment: the package itself just interprets the keys in the order they appear, so width then trim would be what I expect but the exact details depend on the code in the driver option file, so it all depends...

Answer (score 3):

The trim works on the original picture as it is easy to test:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[clip,trim=3cm 0cm 0cm 0cm]{example-image-A}

\includegraphics[clip,trim=3cm 0cm 0cm 0cm,width=2cm]{example-image-A}

\includegraphics[clip,width=2cm,trim=3cm 0cm 0cm 0cm]{example-image-A}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In both cases, 3cm was removed from the original. What if I would like to scale by width, and then remove 3cm from the final product?

Comment: @kando I suspect this deserves another question?